# array_unique not removing duplicates

Tags: php

I got an issue with `array_unique` where duplicate values are not being removed.

```
<?php
    $mfgName = 'blah';
    $prodModel = '178.211';
    $name ='178.211 remove this number';

    $input = array($mfgName, $prodModel, $name);
    $st =array_unique($input);
    $str= implode(' ', $st);
    echo $str;
?>
```

Output should be:

```
blah 178.211 remove this number
```

but I get:

```
blah 178.211 178.211 remove this number
```

Comment: `blah != 178.211 != 178.211 remove this number`

Comment: I don't see an issue here? That seems to be exactly how everything should work. Sounds like you need to write your own `unique` function that checks for indexes of every string in every other string.

Comment: Please check this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) to know  how array_unique works !

Comment: The thing which you are trying is wrong... tell me your exact need... so that i can help you... array_unique remove only duplicate entries from the array here.....  '178.211'!='178.211 remove this number' are different

Comment: Some occurrences  of $name has $prodModel in them . i want  to check if $prodModel exist in $name then remove  $prodModel . other wise  keep it   .     just read array_unique and i dont think it will do what i want it to..any suggestion please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change

```
 $input = array($mfgName, $prodModel, $name);
```

into

```
$input = array_merge(array($mfgName, $prodModel), explode(" ",$name));
```

This splits the string `$name` in an array and array_unique works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

You could use explode on $name to get the individual words in it and construct an array containing $prodModel and the words of $name and then use $array_unique to get rid of the repeated words.

```
$nameWords = explode(' ', $name);
array_push($nameWords, $prodModel);
$uniqueWords = array_unique($nameWords);
$result = implode(' ', $uniqueWords);
```